# Making topographic basemap visible in layout using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, layouts, arcgis-online-basemaps, visibility

I am using ArcGIS Pro 2.8.

I have a basemap and river labels are not visible in the layout.

How do I make them visible?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have a read of this [article](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000019873).